# Notification on screen orientation change

Tags: .net, windows-7, events, notifications, screen-orientation

Windows 7, .NET 3.5
I need to know when netbook (small laptop, but normal Windows 7) changes orientation (there is a button on the netbook that is used to switch landscape/portrait orientation).

This tells me the orientation, but I am looking for the change notification event:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ScreenOrientation
```

Do I have to reference `WindowsMobile` to get that?

Comment: The best way I've found to figure out which event I need to handle is to use spy++ or similar, take the action I want to handle, and note the events that fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such event as far as I am concerned. There is however a [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812142.aspx) covering this using a different technique. I guess you could write some sort of wrapper for this to work with `ScreenOrientation`

Comment: I'd give you +1 for the link but you said there's no such event when the article you linked to says the event is the Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged event.

Comment: @David Stratton, I'm sorry yes you are correct. But the `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ScreenOrientation` is not directly compatible with the `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged` event. You'll still have to code something around it.